# How do I stop Windows Defender from scanning files that are opened?

Tags: c#, windows, file

I am having an issue with Windows Defender when I open a file using:

```
new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Windows Defender will always attempt to scan the file I am attempting to read via the service  msmpeng.exe. This scan is making performance severely degrade, because the files are not on a true random access device.

Is there some way in C# or Visual Studio to stop Windows Defender from scanning the files I am attempting to open? Or is forcing the user to add an exception specifically for my application the only option?

Comment: Random thought, contradictory opinions welcome: I would certainly hope that there's no API to disable an antivirus program from scanning files without user confirmation. Noting your description **the files are not on a true random access device**. Is this a situation confined to a small group of workstations? Can you create an exception for all files on this particular device?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is designed with linear and semi-linear devices in mind and is not confined to a small group of users.  I am wondering if there is something i could be doing for my opening of files to read them to not be considered suspicious.